# How do arithmetic operations using functions in GNU bash?

Tags: bash, macos

```
function _4 () {
    4
}
echo $((_4 + _4))
```

That result is:`0`

The result cannot be zero, because it is a sum of two numbers greater than zero.

Comment: I suggest to replace `4` in your function with `echo "4"`.

Answer (score 4):

In an arithmetic context, all identifiers undergo parameter expansion, recursively if necessary, until you either get an integer or an undefined parameter (which is treated as 0).

If you want to call a function, you need to use a command substitution:

```
echo $(( $(_4) + $(_4) ))
```